# request: adding "no. of workers" in the server report

Tags: logging, g-wan

by gwan_1 or gwan -w 1,
gwan limits the no. of workers to ONE.
but i can't find it in the server report.

there is only such information as below in the report:

```
Processes: 436  
CPU(s): 1 Intel(R) Pentium(R) Dual CPU E2180 @ 2.00GHz (2 Cores/CPU, 1 threads/Core)  
Allowed: 2 Cores
```

this information was kept unchanged even when i ran gwan by renaming to gwan_1 or by gwan -w 1.

it is necessary to show the no. of workers in the server report.

thnks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This portion of the log file reports the machine configuration.

Starting with G-WAN v3.8 the `number of worker threads` is also reported in the `gwan.log` file (here with `./gwan_2`):

```
1 Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5620 @ 2.4GHz (4 Cores/CPU, 2 threads/Core)
Using 2 worker threads
```

There are also with many new things (like servlet size and fingerprint) in the gwan.log file now.

Comment: **Where can i download the 3.8+**, since the latest gwan in the gwan.ch is 3.3.28?

Comment: v3.8 is a beta release. alpha and beta versions are not publicly published. Only a few partners and customers get them (usually when they ask and get a new feature, or when they spot a bug blocking their developments).